# Uploading file on my Google drive with automatic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to Develop an ASP.Net Web Application to allow my clients to upload/ delete/ edit files on my Google drive with automatic authentication. If anyone has any idea on this please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a service account and check the documentation

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You need to at least attempt things on your own.  Google is a very usefull tool for finding documentation.

Comment: You opened my eyes thanks for your help